# Pyspark - HashingTF treating "egg can" and "can egg" the same?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hash, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Some code is not working as expected.  It appears than the HashingTF function is returning the same hash for strings with exactly the same words, regardless of the order of the words. Can someone confirm?

```
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=mytokenizer.getOutputCol(), 
outputCol="features")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  HashingTF treats the input as a "bag of words" (independent of word order). If the "bags" are the same, you get the same hash.